# Trying to get content type from a node entity

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm trying to get the content type from a node entity.

The entity is being loaded as follows:

```
$synclist = entity_load_single('entity_synclist', $qid);
```

Now, how would I then get the content type? Would it be as simple as:

```
$contenttype = $synclist->type;
```

Or do I have to do some other Drupal magic?

Answer (score 4):

You're not loading a node there, you're loading an entity of type `entity_synclist`. Its bundle key *might* be `type`, but it depends on what's defined in the module's implementation of `hook_entity_info()`.

To be sure, you can get that information from the entity definition and use it to get the bundle like so:

```
$info = entity_get_info('entity_synclist');
$bundle_key = $info['entity keys']['bundle'];

$synclist = entity_load_single('entity_synclist', $qid);
$bundle = $synclist->$bundle_key;
```

Comment: There's no need to put a single variable in `{}` just `$synclist->$bundle_key;` is enough.

Comment: @chx Yeah, I've been in the Python world recently and they have an "explicit is better than implicit" philosophy - guess it's rubbed off on my PHP too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module, you could do a `dpm($synclist)` in the code.

This will display the all the properties of the node entity. I think you are on the right track.

We just need to verify the type property is referred to as that.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested here to use the bundle key from the entity into - this is just overdose for me.

Someone suggested to use devel - but this will display the node type only when you via the UI and not progrematiclly.

When using a node, or any other entity, when you know that the type the key you can use it as you suggested - just use the $node->type. Another thing you can use is the entity metadata wrapper which is a helpful tool - you can access field and properties the same way but it's also contain some good function:

$wrapper->getBundle() in order to get the type of the entity($node->type).

$wrapper->label() in order to get the title of the entity($node->title, $user->name).

$wrapper->getIdentifier() in order to get the ID of the entity($node->nid, $user->uid) and many other functions.